# Sqlalchemy, именование файлов и классов

Tags: python, sqlalchemy

Интересуют так называемые "best practices"

Пример: у нас есть таблица players. Как именовать класс и файл (единственное или множественное число)

players.py

```
class Player:
    __tablename__ = 'players'
```

Comment: Таблица `players`, потому что в ней будут храниться записи по игрокам. А класс `Player` (с заглавной буквы в [верблюжьей нотации](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/CamelCase)), потому что он описывает одного игрока.

Comment: @Jazzis - а имя файла `players.py` принципиально во множественном числе?

Comment: В единственном. Смотря что вы в нем будете описывать. Хотя, вроде, это не так принципиально.

Answer (score 1):

если будешь импортировать через from ***** import * название файла всё-равно уберётся, поэтому мне всёравно

```
from players import *
a = Player()
```

Если же через import ** то название файла будет прибавляться

```
import players
a = players.Player()
```

Но опять же я считаю что всё равно